# Ember Data: pushing many records to store is slow

Tags: performance, ember.js, ember-data

I store nearly 7000 records in Ember Data model and pushing them to store is super slow... After the records are added to the store, everything works fine but the process of adding them freezes the browser for about one second.

A quick example:

```
var models = _.range(10000).map(function(i) {
  return Ember.Object.create({id: "user" + i});
});
var store = App.__container__.lookup('controller:base').store;

store.pushMany('user', models); // this takes about 2000 ms
```

As my application should not freeze whatsoever, I ended up with one record with an array of 7000 rows and this solution is pretty fast.

However, I'd love to leverage the power of Ember Data records.

Is there any way of solving it? Other than Web Workers? :)

Thanks!

Comment: So jakeii is right, for loop and createRecord are faster, but in this particular case what kind of model do you have with 7000 items, and what portion of Ember Data are you leveraging to make it worth the overhead?

Comment: Due to the way execution works in Javascript: while a function in JavaScript is running, everything else has to wait. Processing events elsewhere doesn't happen until that function is complete, with a UI "lock up" as a result. My guess is that `store.pushMany()` is a single synchronous loop and locking event execution while it runs.

Comment: @Kingpin2k: it's the categories like sport, media, gender. Next step is to make it a dynamic list (actually, a tree) as the users will be given the opportunity to add new categories, edit and remove and nest them and that would be nice to have it as records.

Comment: @andrusieczko Do you really need all the categories in your app at the same time, they can't all be used surely? Could you not just load them from the server as required?

Comment: @Jakeii: yes, they all can be used at the same time. I've got a searchable combo box where you can either go all the levels down (tree) or you can use search to filter through them.

And yes, I was considering doing it like:


- you're on the level N, prefetch most probable data from level N+1 (api call)


- if you use search, you have to make the api call


but that's gonna be a 1. worse user experience, 2. the number of requests will be too big...

Comment: regarding my latest comment: the way with api calls seems to be the smartest solution here and I was wrong: 1. it won't be a worse user experience (today HTTP requests are pretty fast), 2. no, they won't be too many, it's safe

Answer (score 0):

rather than creating the records manually, and pushing them into the store, just call `createRecord`, this causes no hanging for me:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    this.store.createRecord('user', {id: 'user' + i});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but unfortunately, I see the exactly the same result... The app is hanging for about a second. It seems to be faster but still it's not enough...
I don't create the records manually; I fetch them normally with `store.find()`, I've just presented what I've realized, who's the offender of bad performance :)